# result of ifconfig->which is my IP address to give to TCP/IP socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip

I have 2 systems.I run ifconfig on both of them.  I am accessing internet through wifi from mobile hotspot.  I am pasting the output of ifconfig of both. I guess IP of both is 127.0.0.1(though I am using 2 different mobiles). I need to communicate between both of them using tcp/ip sockets. Please confirm me. And better if I can get a c program to find self IP address. If both IPs are same, need to change their IP address. why IP of both devices are same? how they are accessing internet? My target device will be 2 embedded devices with sim cards using gprs for socket communication.

System1->

```
enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 2c:56:dc:29:7f:66  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 233  bytes 15817 (15.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 233  bytes 15817 (15.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.26  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 2405:204:f184:563e:e0f8:7b7e:3ea4:244b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e9a9:9f55:2fd4:2255  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2405:204:f184:563e:f2da:16c6:1bd5:15ee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 80:a5:89:3d:85:3b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 403  bytes 307722 (307.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 945  bytes 134915 (134.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

system 2->

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:26628 (26.6 KB)  TX bytes:26628 (26.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:02:9b:84:a4:72  
          inet addr:192.168.43.217  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2405:204:f184:563e:5d6b:9906:ff66:ab2c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2405:204:f184:563e:e602:9bff:fe84:a472/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::e602:9bff:fe84:a472/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1659 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:964 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:545249 (545.2 KB)  TX bytes:179680 (179.6 KB)
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback addres. You can't connect to it from outside. You should use the 192.168.*.* addresses.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `127.0.0.1` is the device `loopback` address, every device that has a network card will have this.

Now as per what you trying to achieve **I need to communicate between both of them using tcp/ip sockets**. If you're using mobile hotspot as router, make sure both devices are connected to one hotspot so they're both on one network, not two different networks.

Then make sure both device's firewall allow inbound/outbound traffic on the tcp port you want to use and you should be able to communicate between two devices.

You will not be able to achieve with both devices connected to two different mobile hotspots(this considered two different networks), as mobile phones don't have a feature where you can add port forwarding rules allow traffic from the internet like a router does.

Comment: So, I want to make 2 embedded devices with 2 sim cards. How can they communicate with each other , if distance between them is suppose 1 km.